# spring boot ResourceLoader traverse the files in the jar package

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jar, filenotfoundexception

I use spring's ResourceLoader to traverse the files in the jar . but i want to know the file's type(directory or file)。

```
Resource resource = defaultResourceLoader.getResource(templatePathPrefix + File.separator + templateSourcePath);
    File templateSourceFile = null;
    try {
         //throws java.io.FileNotFoundException:
        templateSourceFile = resource.getFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot find file " + resource, e);
    }
 if (templateSourceFile.isDirectory()) {
    System.out.println("it is directory");
 } else {
    System.out.println("it is just file");
 }
```

I know:

```
resource.getInputStream()
```

can get the file's content. but i want to know the file's type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring's `ResourceLoader` is made for creating a resource handler for a resource on the classpath, filesystem, web etc.
It's purpose is not to traverse contents of jar files and probe for file vs directory.

I am not sure what you end goal here is, but for a single loaded resource from `ResourceLoader` you can do something like:

```
String filename = resource.getFilename();
String type = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(resource.getFilename());
```

which will give you the file type, guessed from the extension.

**Traversing Jar Entries**

In order to traverse all jar entries, you have to load the jar file at runtime and do something like:

```
    //String or File handler to JAR file
    JarFile jar = new JarFile(file);
    Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = jar.entries();

    while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
        JarEntry jarEntry = entries.nextElement();
        System.out.println(jarEntry.getName() + ": " + jarEntry.isDirectory());
    }

    jar.close();
```

Another approach would be to open the jar file as a Zip and use [ZipEntry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.html) to probe for file vs directory, or to create a new filesystem for the Jar's content ([FileSystems.newFileSystem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystems.html#newFileSystem-java.net.URI-java.util.Map-)) and then you can work with `Path` and `File` directly.